# How to use like operator outside SELECT

Tags: oracle

I have the following query which works fine.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'ABC','DEF' FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1,col2 FROM DUMMY
) A;
```

I want to apply the like key word on the first column returned by the nested query. I tried the following:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'ABC','DEF' FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1,col2 FROM DUMMY
) A
WHERE COL1 LIKE 'A%';
```

But the above query did not work. I'm getting the error:   ORA-00904: "COL1": invalid identifier.

The fiddle link for the same is as follows:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c54b/7

Please could anybody guide me on how I can achieve the same?

**Edit:** I'm also trying to get the columns from the existing table as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When using *union*, column names or aliases have to be matched on both tables.
- You can call already defined column names and aliases.

Do not forget define column alias('ABC' as col1)

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM 
(
    SELECT 'ABC' as col1,'DEF' as col2 FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'GHI' as col1,'JKL' as col2 FROM DUMMY
) A
WHERE COL1 LIKE 'A%';
```

I think you are trying something like;

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM 
(
    SELECT col1,col2 FROM DUMMY
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col1,col2 FROM DUMMY2
) A
WHERE col1 LIKE 'A%';
```

Have a look at another sample from me on [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/368e34/1)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same without an alias name?

Comment: Hello @Yusuf, I've editted my question. I'm also trying to get the columns that exist in the table as well. Actually my main query just contains the sub-query part (the one inside the brackets). The outer query was just added for using the like key word since it would be a problem to edit the query with the alias name, because the sub-query is an output from another table's column.

Comment: @D_ROCKS ok I edited the answer too. Have a look link at the end of the answer